# Step-down conversion materials

Tags: heatsink, ac-dc, step-down

I have an ac adapter on which I would like to *reduce the output*, from 24 vdc to let's say 6 vdc. What *type* of diodes should I use and *how many*? What about heat dissipation?

Comment: Reducing voltage with diodes for that range is not practical - you should probably use a DC-DC converter.  What current do you require?

Comment: You should use a regulator, either linear if power is low or switching if you need a lot of power.

Comment: you must define the power needed 1st ,load type or current

Comment: peter-bennett - current is essentially non- existent: approx.3mA. I'm really just piddling around w/old parts, etc.Load time would be intermittent:; 3-5 min @ a time.

Comment: user1850479 - Yes a voltage regulator would be efficient. However incongruous it sounds, this project isn't about efficiency. This is more for the  want of knowing.

Comment: tony-stewart-ee75 -:Yes, I see my error. My first foray on this type of platform, so thank u for the info.

Comment: Using a linear regulator is no more efficient (and switching probably less at this load), rather it is easier and will give you a more stable output voltage. Stacking diodes will work too, but the voltage will be off by some and will drift with temperature/load, so it's not as useful.

Answer (score 0):

For diode "type" you might use one a zener diode of about 18v, (a data sheet for the selected zener will give information on power dissipation, tolerance, etc, and likely an example circuit. The power rating of the zener diode would need to be at least Vz x I. If you were not able to find an 18v zener at the needed power rating using two 9v parts would also work (as for other multiples of the required voltage drop). The power dissipation would be shared equally as long as the zener values were all the same.

As for using standard silicon diodes, that does get a bit ridiculous, but if you must, figure about a 0.65v drop per diode, the wattage of each is then 0.65v x I. Note that with that many diodes the resulting voltage drop could vary significantly as the forward voltage of a low cost silicone diode is not well specified. Also there would be a considerable temperature drift.

As in the other comments, using a simple voltage regulator is the more practical method. You should be able to find a 6v "LM7806" 3-pin regulator for a relatively low cost, (possibly costing less, and much easier to wire up then a hand full of diodes).

Answer (score 0):

As in many situations there are several possible solutions. Depending on the cicumstances, one might be better than the other.
Using just diodes to step down a voltage is seldom the best solution...

So let's see what the possibilities are:

1. Silicon Diodes in Series

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fndUVr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

22 Standard silicon diodes will do the job... I put in a load of 100Ohm which results in around 60mA of current which the 1N4148 can handle. If you need more current you can use a 1N4001 (1A), 1N4004 (4A) or 1N4007 (7 amps). But you might see that this solution is not optimal and the voltage will vary greatly with the load.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhn2U6.png)</sup>

One Zener Diode with 18V Zener Voltage can do the trick too... Keep in mind that this Diode can only take 1W which means that above 50mA of load current (like with my 100 ohm example load) the Z-Diode might overheat.

Also note, that variations in the input voltage will be reflected in the output voltage with this system. That's probably not what you want!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fx9iQb.png)</sup>

This is the common way to sue zeners. It's more stable to changes in input voltage. But it only allows for really small currents.

So what you might want:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fN6qXe.png)</sup>
That's a linear regulator and the stuff you might want. Only thing you have to car for is heat. You'll have 18V drop over the 7806 which means, that without cooling you can get around 50mA out of it if you get one in a TO-220 case. Maximum current is normally 1-1.5amps which would mean that you need to get rid of 18-24W of heat which requires quite a beefy cooling solution. The nice thing on theose linear regulators is that they have over current protection as well as thermal protection built in.

So if you need mA in the single digit range, a solution with a Zener-Diode might be ok.
If you need tens of mA up to maybe 100mA a linear regulator can be a good solution.
Above 250mA (at that kind of voltage drop) only a switching regulator makes sense.

Comment: The 1N400x series are all 1A rated. The last digit indicates the diodes' *voltage* rating, not current.